# initializing schema object type vs. package type

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I have the following code:

```
declare
    type r_rec is record (col1 number, col2 varchar2(10));
    type t_rec is table of r_rec;
    v_rec t_rec := t_rec();
begin

       v_rec.EXTEND(2);
       v_rec(1).col1 := 1;
       v_rec(1).col2 := 'one';

       v_rec(2).col1 := 2;
       v_rec(2).col2 := 'two';

    for i in v_rec.first .. v_rec.last
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('col1 = ' || v_rec(i).col1 || ', col2 = ' || v_rec(i).col2); 
    end loop;
end;
```

Which works as expected.

Instead of PLSQL type I want to use schema object type and the code becomes:

```
create or replace type r_rec as object (col1 number, col2 varchar2(10));
/
create or replace type t_rec as table of r_rec;
/

declare
    v_rec t_rec := t_rec();
begin

     v_rec.EXTEND(2);
     v_rec(1).col1 := 1;
     v_rec(1).col2 := 'one';

     v_rec(2).col1 := 2;
     v_rec(2).col2 := 'two';

    for i in v_rec.first .. v_rec.last
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('col1 = ' || v_rec(i).col1 || ', col2 = ' || v_rec(i).col2); 
    end loop;
end;
/
```

But, this time, the following error occurs:

> ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count ORA-06512: at line 7 ORA-06512: at
>   "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Can someone spot what am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: *"Which works as expected."* Umm, no it doesn't. It hurls `06533. 00000 -  "Subscript beyond count"` as expected.

Comment: @APC: you are right; I missed the initialization. I edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code sample fails with `ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8ed5c2f8cd3f4a7bf749bc347e1b2467).

To fix it you need to `EXTEND` the collection:

```sql
declare
    type r_rec is record (col1 number, col2 varchar2(10));
    type t_rec is table of r_rec;
    v_rec t_rec := t_rec();
begin
    v_rec.EXTEND(2);

    v_rec(1).col1 := 1;
    v_rec(1).col2 := 'one';

    v_rec(2).col1 := 2;
    v_rec(2).col2 := 'two';

    for i in v_rec.first .. v_rec.last
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('col1 = ' || v_rec(i).col1 || ', col2 = ' || v_rec(i).col2); 
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Your second code sample has the same issue; you need to `EXTEND` the collection but you also need to initialise the objects:

```sql
create or replace type r_rec as object (col1 number, col2 varchar2(10));
create or replace type t_rec as table of r_rec;

declare
    v_rec t_rec := t_rec();
begin
    v_rec.EXTEND(2);
     v_rec(1) := r_rec( 1, 'one' );
     v_rec(2) := r_rec( 2, 'two' );

    for i in v_rec.first .. v_rec.last
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('col1 = ' || v_rec(i).col1 || ', col2 = ' || v_rec(i).col2); 
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Which outputs:

```
col1 = 1, col2 = one
col1 = 2, col2 = two
```

or you can initialise the values inline in the declaration:

```sql
declare
    v_rec t_rec := t_rec( r_rec( 1, 'one' ), r_rec( 2, 'two' ));
begin
    for i in v_rec.first .. v_rec.last
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('col1 = ' || v_rec(i).col1 || ', col2 = ' || v_rec(i).col2); 
    end loop;
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0e752f607ec44aa6f1a4fd411582e0f0)

Comment: You were right, I missed the initialization. Even so, from your comment, I spotted the mistake. it was      v_rec(1) := r_rec( 1, 'one' ); instead of v_rec(1).col1 :=  1; v_rec(1).col2 :=  'one'